# If the convolution of two signals is a unit impulse, what does this tell us?

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, transfer-function, stability

I have two discrete-time LTI systems whose transfer functions satisfy $h_1[n] * h_2[n]= \delta[n]$. We also know that system 1 is **causal and stable**. Does $h_1[n] * h_2[n]= \delta[n]$ tell us anything about $h_2$?

Intuitively, I would say that $h_2[n]$ is stable, but I don't have any idea how to reason about it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It tells us that the systems are inverses of each other. The DFT of

$$h_1[n]*h_2[n]= \delta[n]$$

is

$$H_1[k] \cdot H_2[k] = 1 $$

so we get

$$H_2[k] = \frac{1}{H_1[k]}, H_1[k] = \frac{1}{H_2[k]}$$

In order for $h_2[n]$ to be causal and stable, $h_1[n]$ has to be minimum phase. Causality and stability of $h_1$ are not sufficient to guarantee causality and stability of the inverse.

A good example of this is an all pass filter. It's perfectly causal and stable but its inverse is anti-causal, i.e. $h_{AP,inv}[n] = h_{AP}[-n]$

Answer (score 1):

Well Hilmar is 100% correct but I want to give a practical application of 2 such systems.

If 2 systems are inverse of each other you can use them to make a noise removing system:

[image]

The block with $H_{1}(z)$ is usually a sensor which measures the main frequencies of the input signal sends them to a PID , then the PID using software sets the resonant frequency.